# Best way to select n-th rows based on data in a field for mySQL table

Tags: mysql, row-number

The final result of this will be used for a graphing application where sometimes we would not want the detailed granularity of data at the level it is stored in the table. This may be hard to phrase in a single question so I will give an example:

Example table:

```
DateTime             AddressID     Amount
1/1/2015 10:00:00    1             10
1/1/2015 10:00:00    2             8
1/1/2015 10:01:00    1             7
1/1/2015 10:01:00    2             12
1/1/2015 10:02:00    1             21
1/1/2015 10:02:00    2             15
etc...
```

Note: The times will always have 00 for the seconds - if that helps.
Note: The entries may NOT always have an entry for every minute, but they generally should. So it is possible some might times might be skipped. But there will always be an entry for both addressIDs (1 & 2) every time without fail.

I need to return the above 3 fields, in a period of time requested (for example past 24 hours), but only for certain increments of time FOR EACH OF THE ADDRESS ID's. For example, records for every 5 minutes, or every 10 minutes.

so in the case of 5 minutes it would return:

```
DateTime             AddressID     Amount
1/1/2015 10:**00**:00    1             10
1/1/2015 10:**00**:00    2             8
1/1/2015 10:**05**:00    1             11
1/1/2015 10:**05**:00    2             17
1/1/2015 10:**10**:00    1             28
1/1/2015 10:**10**:00    2             5
etc...
```

Performance is very important. I hope I explained that well enough for someone to get the idea of what I need and I thank you in advance for your suggestions.

EDIT: For clarification, the 5 minutes in the above example should be the minimum time BETWEEN each row. So, if in the above example, on the rare chance that there was a missing time entry for 10:05:00 it should not simply select the 10:10:00 row, it should select the 10:06:00 record and then the next row selected would be 10:11:00, etc.

Comment: Do the values in your desired output come from rows not shown in your sample data? What happens when data is missing?

Comment: Yes all of the rows will need to be returned (and others not shown above).

Comment: And when data is missing it should go to the next value (I edited my question for clarity on that point).

Comment: I would do a select with a where clause on the time and sort it decending and Limit it to 3

Select x,y,z from mytbl where time>10:30:00 desc limit 0,3

Comment: ^^^ How would that produce my desired results? That would simply return the 3 oldest rows. That's not even close to providing the results I need.

Comment: What i understood from your question is 
U need 3 subsequent record from a time u give. That query will give you that.

Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No please read the question carefully. It could very well return hundreds of records but they all must be "spaced" evenly by a certain number of minutes each, for each address id.